# Why is my Japanese Macbook keyboard not being recognized properly?

Tags: keyboard, mojave, japanese

My keyboard looks like this

[image]

I have just upgraded to Mojave and now osx will not recognize the proper keyboard layout and some characters do not match like @ and others.

I have gone into keyboard preferences several times but osx doesnt have any options to change the layout.

Comment: Do you see these problems when your input source is set to US or when it is set to Japanese or both?

Comment: In your Japanese input preferences, what is your setting for Romaji layout?